# Pow() function in C

Tags: c, double, pow, math.h

Here is the code that I couldn't figure out why it's not working (I'm always getting a result like `0.000000`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    double num,b;
    printf("Write a number between 0 and 256"); scanf("%lf",&num);
    num = pow(2.0,b);
    printf("%lf",b);    
    return 0 ;
}
```

Here, the answer of the **pow** is known as **num** since it's introduced by user, and I'm trying to find the value of **b** which is inside the function!

Actually, I saw similar questions here, but some of them were dependent on a solution of **gcc**, (I'm using **Dev C++**) and the rest had a structure which is slightly different and the problem may arise due to this difference.

Comment: `b` is not initialized. Thus, your code exhibits Undefined Behavior.

Comment: "Here, the answer of the pow is known as num since it's introduced by user, and i'm trying to find the value of b which is inside the function!" makes no sense to me

Comment: You're storing the inputted value in num and then overwriting it with 2 to the power of undefined.

Answer (score 7):

You probably meant

```
b = pow(2.0, num);
```

at the seventh line. As the [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/) says, the prototype of the `pow` method is:

```
double pow (double base, double exponent);
```

So you will get the calculated result returned from the given in parameters.

If you actually meant that you are looking for the base 2 logarithm, then you should use logarithm:

```
b = log2(num);
```

This works in C99 using the `<tgmath.h>` header, or you can use the solution in [@SleuthEye](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29370843/2102532)'s answer

The header include also has a typo, as [@Paul R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/253056/paul-r) commented.

Comment: Thank you guys, i still need a time to think as a programmer :) That's why i insisted on using 'pow' where i could be used 'log' perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

To get the value of `b` for which `pow(2.0,b) == num`, you should use [logarithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm) (which is related to the inverse of `pow`) to obtain:

```
b = log(num)/log(2.0);
```

Answer (score 1):

C is not math. It will not try to find the value of `b` for you. You're actually passing its value(which contains garbage) as a parameter, and storing the undefined result of `pow()` in `num`, overwriting whatever was that you read in there. Then, you display the undefined value of `b`, witch is zero probably because you're in debug mode.

For your purposes, try using `log()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize `b`. You used `#include<math.h.>` , which's wrong. Try `#include<math.h>`.